# Testing single page application

Tags: angularjs, symfony, testing, single-page-application, ng-admin

I am conceiving an SPA with the following tools:

Rest backend: Symfony + FosRestBundle + JMSSerializerBundle.
Front admin panel: ng-admin + angular.

My question: how to test an SPA, is there a specific workflow?
Do I have to use selenium or just write functional tests with the Symfony WebTestCase utilities ?